WYSIWYG редактор для ASP.NET Core
Какой есть WYSIWYG редактор, чтобы используя его готовые инструменты, в приложении ASP.NET Core можно было бы сохранять картинки в тексте. Например я хотел использовать ckeditor, но ckfinder для сохранения картинок работает максимум с ASP.NET. А написать подобное самостоятельно я не смогу, тем более мне проект сдавать и времени немного осталось.
